# Q object for CheckConstraint

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-orm

I'm trying to write a Q object that says

> Either one of these 4 fields is not null, or this field is not true

I have a normalized table with 4 category of prices, and an available flag

```
price_A
price_B
price_C
price_D
available_on_the_store
```

I want at least one of these prices to be populated before it is possible to mark it as available_on_the_store on a CheckConstraint with a Q object

I can easily do this with a huge Q chain or can easily write it in .clean() and force it in the python side, yet I want it to be in the database level; so please answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write this as:

```
  Q(available_on_the_store=False) |
  Q(price_A__isnull=False) |
  Q(price_B__isnull=False) |
  Q(price_C__isnull=False) |
  Q(price_D__isnull=False)
```

or we can write it shorter with:

```
Q(
    ('available_on_the_store', False),
    ('price_A__isnull', False),
    ('price_B__isnull', False),
    ('price_C__isnull', False),
    ('price_D__isnull', False),
    _connector=Q.OR
)
```

You thus can make a model that looks like:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # …

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                Q(
                    ('available_on_the_store', False),
                    ('price_A__isnull', False),
                    ('price_B__isnull', False),
                    ('price_C__isnull', False),
                    ('price_D__isnull', False),
                    _connector=Q.OR
                ),
                name='one_price_not_null_if_avaiable'
            )
        ]
```

Comment: I seem to be able to mark it as `available_on_the_store=True` when all the price fields are null, and the `obj.save()` doesn't seem to complain at all. Should throw IntegrityError or something, right?

Comment: @Işık Kaplan: not all databases actually check constraints, for example free versions of MySQL 5.7 is not implemented (it ignores the constraint). You also need to run migrations to add the constraints (and the database should, like said, support checking constraints (and this should be enabled).

Comment: I'm on psql, and it is already migrated; and the uniqueconstraints seems to work by default, should I enable something for the CheckConstraints to work?

Comment: @IşıkKaplan: what if you run `manage.py sqlmigrate app_name migration_name`? Can you see the constraint, can you edit the question and include the SQL migration?

Comment: Done, seems weird tho; why does it say =0 instead of some sort of null indicator, idk sql so this is a bit confusing haha.

Comment: I apparently just skipped all the `__isnull` part, should've realized it from the SQL output; am trying with isnull and if it works I'll come back.